# Mule deployment and config properties file

Tags: deployment, mule, properties-file

Our application deployed in mule server has credentials in properties file that are used to access Database and other cloud. We have to do some change in properties file. I would like to know whether this will require a redeployment of the running application or it would be sufficient to restart the application from  mule managent console or a server restart may be required.

Any suggestion would greatly help.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can still control the applications from MMC, even when they are deployed using the $MULE_HOME/apps directory.  You navigate to them through the "Servers" tab.  Find the application under the server, and there is an option at the top right to "Stop" and "Start" the application.  This should allow you to run with the new configuration values.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest possible without restarting your Mule Server is to Redeploy the application from the Mule Management Console (Deployment tab).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have the applications previously deployed by placing in the apps directory and hence they are not shown under the deployments tab.So will the change in properties file will reflect only after a server restart.